# interpreting this for loop snippet

Tags: java

Here we have a snippet of an array implementation of a binary heap. I would like some help seeing what this for loop means in pseudocode:

```
public void insert (Anytype x) { 
    int hole = ++currentSize; //currentSize is the size of the array
    for (array[0] = x; x.compareTO(array[hole / 2]) < 0; hole /= 2)
        array[hole] = array[hole / 2];
    array[hole] = x;
}
```

I can't seem to understand how this for loop works. Thank you.

**EDIT** filled the hole

Comment: can you post more part of code,like implementation of compareTO?

Comment: @Max hole is `that` (blushes)

Comment: @Sean As long as we don't knwo what `AnyTpye` is and how `AnyType.comprareTO()` is implemented, we can't really help you.

Comment: Well, `currentSize` is just a tad smaller than `hole`... This question got even better than the one about breeding dogs yesterday...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array converted into a binary heap can be seen as follows

```
         [elem 0] <-- put the inserted element here? (why? a precaution perhaps?)

         [element 1]...
    [element2] [ element3 ]  
[elem4][elem5] [elem6][elem7]  
[x][x] [x][x]  [x][XX] ... <-- unoccupied
```

The code travels to the parent of each node by dividing the index hole by 2.
Then it moves the parent up to the current node, if parent > current node.

There's a mistake I think... At least this is not the typical solution, where one puts the inserted element as the last non occupied 'hole' and travels up from that position....

The correct method is just start comparing the parent of the last element and iterate towards root. There is no need to swap, but where ever index 'hole' ends, that's the proper place to finally put the new element. (The typical solution puts 'X' in the last position and *swaps*, but that is inefficient. ) Also the first initialization in the for loop is unnecessary.

Anyway, the index arithmetic works when index 0 is omitted.

Comment: So, there is no mistake other than the unnecessary assignment array[0]=x

Comment: you are correct. i found that this implementation only works when index 0 is omitted. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're looking for, but here goes:

compareTo returns an int. x.compareTo(y) returns a negative number if x is less than y.

So the code roughly does this:

```
for( set the first pos in the array to x; if x is less than array[hole/2]; hole/=2){
   array[hole] = array[hole/2];

Set your arr[final val of hole] to x
```